# Хотелось бы что бы кто нибудь объяснил код на C++ (перемешивание символов строки)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, случайные-числа

Ниже я пометил, где непонятно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    //выбор слова
    enum schet{WORD, HINT, NUM_FIELDS};
    const int MAX_SLOV = 2;
    const string array[MAX_SLOV][NUM_FIELDS] =
    {
        {"glasses", "Помогаю видить, в жару не щюрешься"},
        {"word","При помощи их ты общаешься"}
    };
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    int choice = rand() % MAX_SLOV;
    string theWord = array[choice][WORD];
    string theHint = array[choice][HINT];
    //перемешивание слова

    //!!! Начиная от сюда и ниже
    string peremeshat = theWord;
    int razmer = peremeshat.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < razmer; i++)
    {
        int index1 = rand() % razmer;
        int index2 = rand() % razmer;
        char vo_vrema = peremeshat[index1];

        peremeshat[index1] = peremeshat[index2];
        peremeshat[index2] = vo_vrema;
    }
    cout << peremeshat.size() << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Этот кусок кода бессмыслен. Проявлением работы этой программы является лишь вывод величины `peremeshat.size()`, которая никак не меняется кодом, который вы попросили объяснить. То есть весь это код можно просто выбросить - на результат работы программы он никак не влияет.

Comment: В дополнение, рекомендую для перемешивания элементов использовать функцию `std::random_shuffle`, определённую в `algorithm`. Подробнее можете почитать [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да тут все просто до невозможности...

Длина строки

```
int razmer = peremeshat.size();
```

Цикл - повтор столько раз, чему равен размер строки

```
for (int i = 0; i < razmer; i++)
{
```

Два случайных символа

```
    int index1 = rand() % razmer;
    int index2 = rand() % razmer;
```

Меняются местами один с другим.

```
    char vo_vrema = peremeshat[index1];
    peremeshat[index1] = peremeshat[index2];
    peremeshat[index2] = vo_vrema;
}
```

Только вот правильное перемешивание - это по Кормену немного не так, там в цикле надо поочередно для каждого символа выполнить обмен со случайно выбранным справа от него. Т.е. в ваших терминах получение случайной перестановки с равномерным распределением получается так:

```
int razmer = peremeshat.size();
for (int i = 0; i < razmer; i++)
{
    int index = i + rand() % (razmer-i);
    char vo_vrema = peremeshat[index];
    peremeshat[index] = peremeshat[i];
    peremeshat[i] = vo_vrema;
}
```

(См. [Кормен, Лейзерсон и др., *Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ, 3 издание*](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1794-2.html), с. 153.)

P.S. Поскольку тут возникают споры о том, насколько равномерным будет распределение перестановок - привожу 2 страницы из указанной книги.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавлю, это это правильное тасование еще называют [тасованием Фишера — Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0).

Comment: Вот эта ерунда из книги?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А что с кодом не так? Это тот же Фишер-Йетс, только цикл в обратную сторону сделан. Смысл вроде не поменялся?

Comment: В этом коде все символы не будут выбираться, так что это не тот же  Фишер-Йетс. Плюс  ничего разумного в коде не вижу...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Почему ерунда? Возьмите книгу тут https://vk.com/doc10903696_305548249?hash=e650748a79ddfa0a8a&dl=b92ea6b663c44a5cc8, и посмотрите стр. 153, с доказательством того, что такие перестановки будут равномерно распределенными.

Comment: @Harry,  речь не том какая перестановка будет, а о том, как написано код и что выведено в конце. Я просто удивлен, что такое пишут в книгах, вот и все. Не имею ничего против ни вопросу  ни ответу

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да понятно, что код не из книги :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: То "тасование", которое реализовано в этом коде, даже отдаленно не похоже на Фишер-Йетса. Реализованое здесь тасование не будет давать равномерного распределения перестановки.

Comment: @AnT Этот вариант даже на Википедии есть: [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), Ctrl+F "An equivalent version".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Мы, наверное, говорим о разных вещах. Я имею в виду именно "наивное" перемешивание в коде из исходного вопроса. Оно равномерным никак не будет. Ваша ссылка на Википедию - совсем другой алгоритм. Разумеется, все варианты Фишер-Йетса дают равномерное перемешивание.

Comment: @AnT Я - про последний кусок кода в ответе, который Harry назвал "правильным перемешиванием".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: С последним куском кода в ответе проблем нет - это обычный Фишер-Йетс. Непонятно только, почему никто до сих пор не применил `std::swap`.

Comment: @AnT Потому что там же написано - **в ваших терминах** :)